# Error when setting kafka configs

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to configure SASL/SCRAM in Kafka. I found this resource[1](Slide 52 Create SCRAM Users) in slide share and when creating users, I get the following error.

```
Error while executing config command requirement failed: Invalid 
entity config: all configs to be added must be in the format
"key=val".
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Invalid entity config: all configs to be added must be in the format "key=val".
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)
at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.parseConfigsToBeAdded(ConfigCommand.scala:128)
at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.alterConfig(ConfigCommand.scala:78)
at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.main(ConfigCommand.scala:65)
at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand.main(ConfigCommand.scala)
```

Here is the configuration that I run.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SCRAM_CONFIG='SCRAM-SHA-256=[iterations=8192,password=kafka123]'
SCRAM_CONFIG="$SCRAM_CONFIG,SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=kafka123]"

./kafka-configs.sh --alter --add-config "$SCRAM_CONFIG" --entity-type users --entity-name stocks_consumer --zookeeper localhost:2181 \

./kafka-configs.sh --alter --add-config "$SCRAM_CONFIG" --entity-type users --entity-name stocks_producer --zookeeper localhost:2181 \

./kafka-configs.sh --alter --add-config "$SCRAM_CONFIG" --entity-type users --entity-name admin --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
```

I could not found any solution for this, so appreciate if I could get a hint to get this working.

EDIT: I'm using Kafka version 2.10.0.10.1.0

Thanks

[1] https://www.slideshare.net/JeanPaulAzar1/kafka-tutorial-kafka-security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.
The support for SASL/SCRAM has been added in the kafka version 0.11 [1]

I did the same in the above version and it worked properly.

Thanks.

[1] https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/0.10.2.0/RELEASE_NOTES.html